# Unequivocally checkout a branch and get latest version in git from a script

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout, git-repo

I am creating a shell build script.

I want it to be called like this:

`./build.sh REPONAME BRANCHNAME`

`$REPONAME` corresponds to a remote. I am assuming that the remote exists.
`$BRANCHNAME` is a branch existing on `$REPONAME`.

`$BRANCHNAME` may have never been checked out on this computer.

So I have this:

```
cd $REPOPATH
git fetch $REPONAME $BRANCHNAME
git checkout --track $REMOTE/$BRANCHNAME
git pull $REPONAME
echo `git rev-parse HEAD`
```

This kind of works but I am experiencing several issues:

- I have to enter my key's private key twice - I guess once for fetch and once for pull. Not critical but if it would be just once, would be better.
- Because of `--track`, if `$BRANCHNAME` was already checked out in the past, I get

> fatal: A branch named $BRANCHNAME already exists

. No idea how fatal that really is but I don't like to see a fatal in the output

- Without the `--track`, I get into detached mode, which I also do not like
- With just `git checkout $BRANCHNAME` I was suddenly getting messages about "ambiguous" branches. Maybe because `$BRANCHNAME` could be on several remotes?

So what is the cleanest and unequivocal way to checkout a branch from a remote, get its latest version and build from it?f

It's astonishing how after so many years using `git` I still don't have a grasp of what feels like must-know skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to discard everything and get the remote version :

```
git fetch $REMOTE
git stash
git checkout $BRANCHNAME
git branch -u $REMOTE/$BRANCHNAME
git reset --hard $REMOTE/$BRANCHNAME
```

If you want to merge the updates from the remote branch in your local branch :

```
git fetch $REMOTE
git stash
git checkout $BRANCHNAME
git branch -u $REMOTE/$BRANCHNAME
git merge $REMOTE/$BRANCHNAME
```

Comment: This looks very promising. Thank you.

Comment: I usually would not have any changes on that branch so the first suggestion looks the most appropriate.

Comment: Some of the actions in my first answer could fail (for example, if `$BRANCHNAME` is your active branch `git branch -f $BRANCHNAME ...` will fail). Edited my answer with something that will perhaps print some warnings such as `Already on '$BRANCHNAME'` but should work.

Comment: I will accept this as this is closes to what I asked. I am currently asking myself though if I just should better clone the repo everytime. Could work for my use-case. But that was not the question :)

Comment: @LeGEC 4th line gives this error: > git branch -u origin/staging
warning: refname 'origin/staging' is ambiguous.
fatal: Ambiguous object name: 'origin/staging'.

Comment: @Shatiz: this means you have two names that can match `origin/staging`. Check `git branch --format="%(refname)" -a | grep staging`, if you see `refs/heads/origin/staging` in that list it means you created a local branch named `origin/staging`. To delete that branch: `git branch -d origin/staging`.